# Oracle TDE cannot find new PKCS#11 library

Tags: oracle, pkcs#11, hsm, tde

I have previously used an Utimaco HSM with Oracle database, but I want to put pcks#11-spy`or`pkcs#11-logger` between the hsm. The Utimaco HSM library is working and I used this command:

```
alter system set encryption key identified by <HSM_passphrase>;
```

But now I am trying to use a the `pkcs11-spy`. But Oracle cannot find the new library and returns the following:

```
alter system set encryption key identified by <HSM_passphrase>;

Error at line 1:
ORA:28376: cannot find PKCS11 library
```

It is unclear for me how to setup the folders in `C:\oracle\extapi\32\hsm\...` for the spies.  In the future I want to build my own pkcs11 library and I will have the same problem of not knowing how to setup the pkcs11 library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was to reinstall the database with a new PKCS#11 library.